# How am I supposed to use the package haskell-type-exts?

Tags: haskell, typechecking

I am trying to typecheck a code snippet provided as a string.

I found the package haskell-type-exts ([hackage link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-type-exts)) which seems to provide what i need: With `parseModule` an AST gets constructed on which `typecheckModule` can be applied. But then I don't know what to do with the result. It is of type `Tc VarEnv` where `Tc` is a monad.

The package provides a test case where something like this is used:

```
ea <- runTc testEnv $ typecheckExp e
```

But `runTc` is in  a hidden module so I cannot use it. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser (parseModule, ParseResult(..))
import Language.Haskell.TypeCheck.TypeCheck
-- import Language.Haskell.TypeCheck.Monad  --hidden module

main = do
    let m = "myTest = map (+1) [1..10]"
    let r = parseModule m
    case r of
         ParseOk res -> printStuff res
         _ -> print "wtf"

printStuff r = do
    let Right tc = return $ typecheckModule r
--    print tc?
```

What am I missing here? Maybe the module is only hidden by mistake?

Comment: I think this package is not yet ready for usage. Just look at the source of Language.Haskell.TypeCheck: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-type-exts/0.1.0/doc/html/src/Language-Haskell-TypeCheck.html#typeCheck  `typeCheck = undefined` typechecks of course! You could try to use the GHC-API ([Haddock](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc/index.html) and [Wiki Page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/As_a_library))

Comment: Seems like you are right and i have no other choice. Thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an experimental third-party software package that was never completed and appears to have been abandoned several years ago. This question is likely unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this package is not yet ready for usage. Just look at the [source of Language.Haskell.TypeCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-type-exts/0.1.0/doc/html/src/Language-Haskell-TypeCheck.html#typeCheck). For example `typeCheck = undefined` typechecks of course!

You could try to use the GHC-API (Haddock and Wiki Page).